# How to set maximum sound on Android 7.1

Tags: android, audio, volume, android-audiomanager, android-7.1-nougat

Open the application sound set to be maximum.

```
NotificationManager n = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(n.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume, 15);

        }else{
            // Ask the user to grant access
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(intent,99);
        }
```

I've used this code android 7.1.1 and no luck.
Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> I've used this code android 7.1.1 and no luck.

**Because** From N onward, volume adjustments that would toggle Do Not Disturb are not allowed unless the app has been granted Do Not Disturb Access. See `isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted().`

[**`boolean isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted())

> added in API level 23
>
> Checks the ability to read/modify notification do not disturb policy for the calling package.
>
> Returns true if the calling package can read/modify notification policy.

Read more about [**`setStreamVolume()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)) of `AudioManager`